# Can't permanently change SYSDATE Format

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I want to change the date format of Oracle
Now it's DD/MM/YYYY, i want to change it to MM/DD/YYYY

I used a simple code (thank you google)

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI';
select sysdate from dual;
```

The problem is when I disconnect and reconnect, the changes are cancelled,

Any help ?

The main of the change is to let Oracle accept insert date with the format MM/DD/YYYY

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should specify the format during the insert (using `to_date()`) rather then relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings. You can change the default format for your sessions - which client are you using? - but one day someone else will run your code and it will break.

Comment: `ALTER SESSION` does what it says: it changes the current session (=connection), not the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this format also in your Registry at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\NLS_DATE_FORMAT`,

resp.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

Example to do this from command line:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1" /v NLS_DATE_FORMAT /t REG_SZ /d "MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI" /f
```

Another possibility is to set the value as Environment Variable, e.g.:

```
set NLS_DATE_FORMAT="MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI"
```

Note, the Environment Variable takes precedence over Registry settings.

But be aware, these just define the **default** value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. It can be changed by `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ...` command at any time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
The problem is that I don't have NLS_DATE_FORMAT in both reg
How can I set it as and Environnement Variable ?

Comment: Do you really ask how to set (or add) a value in your Registry or how to define an Environment Variable? Google for "Add value to Registry", you will get hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in your command you're altering session. So after reconnect you have new session that gets server settings. For better understanding please read:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76966/ch2.htm

I would recommend to insert dates always with `to_date(data_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')` and not trust that NLS won't be changed.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not that good in database admin,
Can you give me the complete query ?

Comment: @HamzaAmami instead of `insert into T (datefield) values ('10/21/2016 23:10')` please use `insert into T (datefield) values (to_date('10/21/2016 23:10',''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'))` The other way means yopu need to change DB settings or env variables what you shouldn't do if you don't have good understanding of administration

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL*Plus, you can add the command to set the nls_date_format in the glogin.sql or login.sql files - see [this helpful guide](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/login.html).

However, if your requirement is "to let Oracle accept insert date with the format MM/DD/YYYY", why not simply convert the string into a date when you insert it, e.g.:

```
insert into some_table (id, date_col)
values (1, to_date('10/25/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

That way, you don't need to worry about formatting issues; it'll automatically be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Do ALTER SYSTEM instead of SESSION:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY' scope=both;
```

or:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';
```

More info [here](http://dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_change_the_default_data_format.htm).